# any subset of $\mathbb{R}$ which is somewhere dense does not have discrete subspace topology

Tags: general-topology, real-numbers

Here's the question:

> Suppose $\mathbb{R}$ has the topology induced by the absolute value
>   metric. Then any subset of $\mathbb{R}$ which is somewhere dense does
>   not have the discrete subspace topology.

---

Here's my attempt of beginning of a proof:

Let $A$ be somewhere dense set in $\mathbb{R}$. Then by definition $(\text{Cl } A)^{\circ} \ne \emptyset$, i.e, there is an nonempty open set $U$ contained in $\text{Cl } A$. We claim that $A \cap U$ is not empty. Suppose $x \in U$ then $x \in \text{Cl } A$ and consequently, every neighborhood of $x$ meets $A$ and thus, $U \cap A$ is not empty.

Let $y \in U\cap A$. We claim that $\{ y \}$ is not open in $A$. Suppose if $\{ y \}$ were open, then $\{ y \} = A \cap U'$ for some open set $U'$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

**Can someone give me some hints from here or provide an alternative proof?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\{y\}$ were open, then $\{y\} = A \cap U'$ for some open set $U' \subset \mathbb R$. Replacing $U'$ by $U' \cap U$, we may assume $U' \subset U$. I.e., $U' \subset \operatorname{Cl}(A)$.

Previously, you have (essentially) shown that every open subset of $\mathbb R$ contained in $\operatorname{Cl}(A)$ has nonempty intersection with $A$. Now apply this to the open set...

> $U' - \{y\}$

... to obtain a contradiction with the assumption that...

> $U' \cap A = \{y\}$.